# VS 2019 Console.WriteLine() versus System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019, blazor, console.writeline

In Visual Studio 2019 I'm unable to get System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine() to show anything in either the Output(Debug) windown nor the Immediate Window.  I've got my options settings for 'Debugging->General->Redirect All Output Windown Text to the Immediate Window' unchecked.

I'm able to see the output of Console.WriteLine in both the browser console and the VS Output window.

My code is a multiproject one with Blazor and razor classes.

I'm looking for a super simple explaination as I've been searching Google trying to find the solution for an hour now and nothing is helping.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you create a new project, did you face the same error?

Comment: Any update about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the same situation as you described in my side.

[image]

And you should check your Vs environment or try the following steps:

**1)** disable any vs installed extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**-->**Installed** to check if there is an extension caused that.

**2)** reset all settings under **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**-->**Reset all settings**. And you can also make a backup about your settings

**3)** use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) under **Developer Command Prompt for VS** to start a pure VS and then test your project there.

**4)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder, then restart your project to test it. Besides, you can also create a new project to test whether the issue happens on a new project.

**5)** make a initial to your VS, close VS, rename `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx` to another name, and it stores all your current settings and environment of VS. Renaming it is equivalent to making a backup. Then, restart VS.

**6)** [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update it to the latest version if there is a new update.

**Besides**, you can also share a small sample about your project to help us troubleshoot the issue.